# Using GooCanvas with Python 3 and GTK+

Tags: python-3.x, canvas, gtk3

I'm trying to write an application with a GUI, which needs a canvas. I'm using Python 3 and GTK+ 3.

I found, that [GooCanvas](https://github.com/dieterv/pygoocanvas) should be appropriate for this, but couldn't even install it or get the demo to work.

Has anyone recently used this library with GTK+ 3? I couldn't find discussions on this, which surprises me. Am I missing something; is there a better canvas available, that I'm failing to find?

Comment: The link you have given points to the GTK+ 2 version of GooCanvas. What you want is the GObject Introspective API which is for GTK+ 3. The API reference is at (https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/#GooCanvas-2.0)

Answer (score 0):

The version for Gtk3 is GooCanvas-2.x. There are still minor problems with GooCanvas, with the appearance of Introspection. Here's a very minimalistic example of 'modern' GooCanvas:

```
from gi.repository import Gtk, GooCanvas

def main(args):
    w = Gtk.Window()
    w.connect('destroy', lambda x: Gtk.main_quit())

    cv = GooCanvas.Canvas()
    cv_root = cv.get_root_item()
    rect = GooCanvas.CanvasRect(
            parent = cv_root,
            stroke_color = 'red',
            x = 10, y = 20,
            width = 40, height = 30)

    w.add(cv)
    w.show_all()
    Gtk.main()

    return 0

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv))
```

The repository system takes some getting used to, but has many benefits.
As far as I know, no 'better' canvases are available. You could use Cairo directly, but GooCanvas takes care of many annoying things, like redrawing the canvas automatically.

**EDIT**:

> ImportError: cannot import name GooCanvas, introspection typelib not
>   found

This means that your installation of introspection was not complete. I suspect you are missing the 'pgi' module in Python. (`pip3 install pgi`), and possibly an updated version of PyGObject (probably available on your distro repository)

Comment: Thanks, but still:
```Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 890, in _find_spec
AttributeError: 'DynamicImporter' object has no attribute 'find_spec'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "t.py", line 3, in <module>
    from gi.repository import Gtk, GooCanvas
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gi/importer.py", line 127, in find_module
    'introspection typelib not found' % namespace)
ImportError: cannot import name GooCanvas, introspection typelib not found```

Comment: Added some info to the previous reply.